# Cross-reference between two worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets (OriginalData & Template) and I'm trying to figure out how to create a vba code that will pull in data from the OriginalData worksheet to the Template worksheet only if a particular cell in a column in the Template worksheet is blank. The data would be populated into another column on the Template worksheet instead of replacing the original blank cell. I would also need to loop through each blank cell within the range of data. I know I can use the VLOOKUP formula, but I'm trying to automate this process as much as possible without having to type in a formula each time.

So far, this is what I've been able to come up with but it doesn't work and now I'm stuck, so any help would be much appreciated. I'm still relatively new to VBA coding, so please go easy on me.

```
Dim shOrg As Worksheet: Set shOrg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OriginalData")
Dim shTemp As Worksheet: Set shTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
Dim CheckCell as Range
LastRowTemp = shTemp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each CheckCell in shTemp.Range("B" & LastRowTemp)
   If CheckCell.Value = "" Then
      Range("C" & CheckCell).Value = Application.VLookup(CheckCell,shOrg.Range("A2:E"),5,FALSE)
   End If
Next CheckCell

End Sub
```

[image: Template Worksheet]
[image: OriginalData Worksheet]

Comment: Try changing `Range("C" & CheckCell).Value` to `Range("C" & CheckCell.Row).Value`. You can alternatively use `CheckCell.Offset(0, 1).Value`.

Comment: It did not work. First, it asked me to define LastRowTemp, which I forgot to do, so I dimmed LastRowTemp as Long. Then, when I ran the macro I get a "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed and the debugger takes me to the line Range("C" & CheckCell.Row).Value = Application.VLookup(CheckCell, shOrg.Range("A2:E"), 5, False).

Comment: `.Range("A2:E")` isn't a range.  You need to specify the row number after the `E`.

Comment: But if I need to pull data from multiple rows within column E, then how do I achieve this? Do I need to create a variable like LastRowTemp, but except it will be LastRowOriginal for the OriginalData worksheet? When I use the macro recorder to see how VLOOKUP plays out, this is what I see, so how would I incorporate this into my existing code?                                                                   
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 ="=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],OriginalData!C[-3]:C[1],5,FALSE)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comment above, the following code will achieve what you want – I.e. defining the number of rows to assess.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AutoVlookup()
Dim shOrg As Worksheet, shTemp As Worksheet
Dim OrgRng As String, TempRng As Range, CheckCell As Range

Set shOrg = Sheets("OriginalData")
Set shTemp = Sheets("Template")

'Define the lookup ranges i.e. the last rows
shOrg.Range("A2:E" & shOrg.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Name = "OrgRng"
Set TempRng = shTemp.Range("B2:B" & shTemp.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each CheckCell In TempRng
    If CheckCell.Value = "" Then
        CheckCell.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,OrgRng,5,FALSE)"
        CheckCell.Offset(, 1).Value = CheckCell.Offset(, 1).Value
    End If
Next CheckCell

End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome, and if you wanted to "automate this process as much as possible" as per your original post, you might consider using a Private Sub on the Template sheet using a `Worksheet_Change()` trigger.

Comment: Gotcha! But may I ask what is the difference between a sub vs. a private sub? And in which instances would I want to use a private sub?

Comment: Here's a starting point for your research :) https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-sub-procedures/#When-To-Make-VBA-Sub-Procedures-Private-An-Example

Comment: You could always post another question in SO asking how to trigger the above code automatically.  That should start your understanding of Private subs & hopefully attract some friendly responses.